# 3D binary volume labeling

Tags: deep-learning, semantic-segmentation, labeling

I'm currently working on labeling a binary segmented volume containing fractured humerus. The objective is to label each component. The following is a volume example I have to label.

[image]

I tried without any success Connected Components Analysis. The problem is the non-complete components separation. Moreover I've tried even Watershed Algorithm, but the dependence to the markers position and their minimum distance are hyperparameters I would not handle in the overall automated process.